# Pass Nested Map from Apex to JavaScript Controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, map

I am currently working on a Lightning Component.
Within my Apex Controller I have a nested map looking like this:

```java
Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<String, LineItem>>>> resultMap = new Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<String, LineItem>>>>();
```

I am able to populate the map within apex, but when I open up `console.log(response.getReturnValue());` in my JavaScript Controller the console only displays `LineItemController$LineItem`.

I have tried different approaches found on StackExchange, unfortunately I wasn't successful.
Anybody has an idea how I can display all of the key/value pairs in the nested map?

Here is some example code:

APEX Controller:

```apex
public class LineItemController {

// Quick Method for creating the map    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<String, LineItem>>>> testNestedMap() { 
        Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<String, LineItem>>>> resultMap = new Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<String, LineItem>>>>();
        
        List<LineItem> lineItemList = new List<LineItem>(); 
        List<LineItem> lineItemList2 = new List<LineItem>(); 
        List<LineItem> lineItemList3 = new List<LineItem>(); 
        List<LineItem> lineItemList4 = new List<LineItem>(); 
        
        lineItemList = createLineItem(1);
        lineItemList2 = createLineItem(10);
        lineItemList3 = createLineItem(100);
        lineItemList4 = createLineItem(100000);
   
        for (LineItem li : lineItemList) {
            resultMap.put(li, new Map<LineItem, Map<LineItem, Map<String, LineItem>>>());   
            for (LineItem li2 : lineItemList2) {
                resultMap.get(li).put(li2, new Map<LineItem, Map<String, LineItem>>());   
                for (LineItem li3 : lineItemList3) {
                    resultMap.get(li).get(li2).put(li3, new Map<String, LineItem>());  
                    for (LineItem li4 : lineItemList4) {
                        resultMap.get(li).get(li2).get(li3).put(li4.code, li4);      
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        system.debug(resultMap);      
        
        return resultMap; 
    }
    
    private static List<LineItem> createLineItem(Integer j) {
        
        List<LineItem> lineItemList = new List<LineItem>(); 
        
        for(Integer i=1; i < 4; i++) {
            LineItem li = new LineItem();
            li.amount=100.0 * Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 10));
            li.code= String.valueOf(i*j);
            li.name='Item ' + (i*j);
            li.revenue=100.0 * Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 10));
            lineItemList.add(li);
        }
        
        return lineItemList;
        
    }
    

    public class LineItem {
        public String code {get; set;}
        public String name {get; set;}
        public Decimal amount {get; set;}
        public Decimal revenue {get; set;}

        public LineItem() {
            this.amount = 0.0;
            this.revenue = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript-Controller:

```js
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var action = component.get("c.testNestedMap");      
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.log(response.error[0].message);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);   
    }
})
```

And last but not least the component:

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable" access="global" controller="LineItemController">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:component>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try JSON/Wrapper approach.

1. JSON - You can pass JSON string from your current apex method instead of sending nested maps with simple statement - `JSON.serialize( nestedMapWhichIsInReturn );`.
2. Wrapper - User wrapper to store all respective maps and send its instance to lightning. However it's also kind of JSON only but you can get some of the variable names to update in the lightning controller.

*Curious to know the actual use-case which has so many maps. If you can mention use case some other ways can be suggested by community to remove complexity(like you're iterating 3-4 nested loops).*

Comment: I described the use-case in a new answer post.Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

First of thanks for your answer, Ysr Shk.

I created a new answer instead of a comment since I try to explain the use-case and need a little bit of space.

I have an object containing the following fields, while all of them a required fields:

- Name
- TopLevelCode (1-digit number)
- SecondLevelCode (2-digit number)
- ThirdLevelCode (3-digit number)
- BaseLevelCode (6-digit code)
- Amount
- Revenue

Some example records look like this:

```
Name; TopLevelCode; SecondLevelCode; ThirdLevelCode; BaseLevelCode; Amount; Revenue
Item 1; 0; 01; 012; 012345; 100; 40000
Item 2; 0; 01; 012; 012789;80; 30000
Item 3; 0; 02; 025; 025025; 200; 100000
Item 4; 9; 90; 902; 902123; 50; 2000
Item 4; 9; 90; 903; 903345; 15; 75000
```

The lightning component should display a kind of a sorted table, while the component should sum up related codes.
In the example above it should display the following when opening the component:

- 0 – Amount: 380 – Revenue: 170000 (sum of amount & revenue for all items with topLevelCode 0)
- 9 – Amount: 65 – Revenue: 77000 (sum of amount & revenue for all items with topLevelCode 9)

When clicking on one of the topLevelCodes the secondLevelCodes should open. Clicking on a secondLevelCode it should open thirdLevelCodes and so on. The final result for the given example should look like this when everything is expanded:

- 0 – Amount: 380 – Revenue: 170000

  - 01 – Amount: 180 – Revenue: 70000

    - 012 – Amount: 180 - Revenue: 70000

      - 012345 – Amount: 100 - Revenue: 40000
      - 012789 – Amount: 80 – Revenue: 30000
  - 02 – Amount: 200 – Revenue: 100000

    - 025 – Amount: 200 - Revenue: 100000

      - 025025 – Amount: 200 - Revenue: 100000
- 9 – Amount: 65 – Revenue: 77000

  - 90 – Amount: 65 - Revenue: 77000

    - 902 – Amount: 50 - Revenue: 2000

      - 902123 – Amount: 50 - Revenue: 2000
    - 903 – Amount: 15 - Revenue: 75000

      - 903345 – Amount: 15 - Revenue: 75000

Within my Apex Controller I currently do all the calculations and put it the map, so that there is only one return parameter. I tried to minimize the calls from JS to Apex.

I hope the given example is understandable :)!

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Pls check this - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tree/example
Here in controller there is one JSON is given and the same is used to render the UI, so you can try that. Imagine map as a JSON key value.So map<String, Object> will give you final json.

Answer (score 0):

A Map object is serializable into JSON only if it uses one of the following data types as a key.

1. Boolean
2. Date
3. DateTime
4. Decimal
5. Double
6. Enum
7. Id
8. Integer
9. Long
10. String
11. Time

that's why you are facing issues in getting the JSON correctly. please try using a **Map key** as one of the above data types.

Maps Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm

Using Custom types: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm

**Note:** if you are using an sObject as a key then the uniqueness is determined on the basis of the field values, but here you are using a custom Apex class type then you must have to implement equals and hashcode contracts(just an extra information)